# Hugo + Blackburn: reading time is not displayed

Tags: time, hugo, blogdown

Is there any change in the usage of `readingTime` parameter in config.toml for displaying the reading time of the posts?

```
[params]
  # Shown in the home page

  dateFormat = "02 Jan 2006, 15:04"

  # Show estimated reading time for posts?
  readingTime = true
```

The above configuration is not working, when used along with Blackburn theme.

Comment: We need more info. What theme are you using? If not using a theme, show the template code that uses that readingTime param.

Comment: Hi, I have used Blackburn theme.

Answer (score 3):

The `readingTime` param is not supported for the Blackburn theme.

See the example site config file for all supported params:
https://github.com/yoshiharuyamashita/blackburn/blob/master/exampleSite/config.toml